# Interchanged data to different clients

Tags: c#, client-server

I have client server application developed in c#. To one server two clients are connected which has get data based on different user credentials. 
Say client1 using Admin credentials and client2 using Guest credentials.
So this two clients gets separate set of data from server based on their credentials.
Some times this 2 clients get their data interchanged. client1 gets client2 data.

Below is my server code for returning data to the client.

```
if (SessionDatabase.currentUser.UserName == "Admin")
                    {
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheXml))
                        {



                            langStr = SessionDatabase.Language;

                            filter = new AllThingzFilter(SessionDatabase, parameters, langStr);



                            filter.Execute();

                            langStr = null;
                            parameters = null;

                            innerXml = filter.XML;
                            cacheXml = innerXml;

                            return innerXml;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return cacheXml;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheTG))
                        {


                            langStr = SessionDatabase.Language;

                            filter = new AllThingzFilter(SessionDatabase, parameters, langStr);



                            filter.Execute();

                            langStr = null;
                            parameters = null;

                            innerXml = filter.XML;
                            cacheTG = innerXml;
                            return innerXml;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return cacheTG;
                        }
```

Comment: Youhave to provide us information about the server implementation, please.

Answer (score -1):

give a try to .net remoting, WCF or web api .. all these can sort ur problem..

Comment: @Liam can u pls tell me whats wrong in it? i have implemented the same, and let me tell u sangeetha posted her code after my answer so i was not able that time to have a look. well its possible to do using .net remoting if u dont know state that clearly..

Comment: this tells the OP virtually nothing. You need to provide examples of practical solutions to his problems. Just saying x technology will help, isn't a good answer